Anylogic - delay/retrieve to match changing schedule
I need to retrieve an amount of agents from a storage block equal to the schedule - getting errors when trying to convert it to an int which isn't working and when the schedule updates the delay remains the same number, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Tried to getNextValue() etc but won't work, stores the value and doesn't update when schedule updates
Image of anylogic simulation

Welcome to AnyLogic and SOF. Pls share code, screenshots or more details. What is the exact problem, what have you tried, what do you see, what do you expect to see? Some tips: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow
